# Share doesnt ask credentials

Tags: network-shares, domain

I got a problem with one share-folder. Its just basic network-share from one VM and idea is that only admins can access to that share.

When im logged with admin-user account I can get to share, but if I go with non-admin-account it just throws me with a pop-up "you have no permissions" or something similar.

And what I want, is that I have change to write admin-credentials on that point so I could access share. No i cant access it with normal user-account at all.

Few points:

1. Its domain-environment.
2. All other users have a mapped drive to same server where is the one im trying to access.
3. I have tried to access admin-share after i have deleted (net use) all connections to that other share i writed on point 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credentials are not per-share, they're per-server. So if you can successfully authenticate to the server *at all*, the client assumes that's OK.

You can use `net use \\host\share /user:DOMAIN\Admin` from the command line to temporarily connect with different credentials (specifying a drive letter is optional).

Some programs can also be run via `runas /user:DOMAIN\Admin /netonly`, however, Explorer itself won't work with it.

Comment: Okay thanks. If thats the best way, then i just have to move that admin-folder to somewhere else :(